# Deploying Angular 2 (quickstart app) to Google Cloud platform

Tags: google-app-engine, angular, deployment, web-deployment

I was trying to deploy the simplest project on Google Cloud platform. The quickstart project can be found [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/setup.html). Locally it works without issues.

However it gets more complicated to get it working on Google Cloud. I know there are a lot of other providers like Heroku with 1-click deployment, but I found it weird that it's not so easy to do it with Google service.

App.yaml

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Package.json - as provided in quickstart project [here](https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json)

The first error I get while deploying (gclould app deploy):

```
angular-quickstart@1.0.0 start /app
tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
sh: 1: tsc: not found
```

Then I add to package.json:

```
"preinstall": "npm install tsc",
```

The second error:

```
tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'moduleResolution'.
error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'lib'.
```

Here I am lost.

Of course I'm using location that supports flex.

**Any ideas if I'm digging the problem in right way** or I should just recreate my project using simple tutorial found at codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-cardboard-viewer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the flex environment if you have any server side code e.g you have written specific server logic to CURD objects.  For client side code you will be better off deploying static files into google storage

Comment: Thanks for clarification, wasn't aware about the difference between flex env and standard. I also found helpful https://jaykhimani.blogspot.com/2016/10/deploying-angular-2-app-with-angular.html and https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-the-angular-cli-for-faster-angular-2-projects.