# Deploying Angular 2 quick-start on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: node.js, angular, google-cloud-platform, angular2-template

I have the same problem as:

[Deploying Angular 2 (quickstart app) to Google Cloud platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41482649/deploying-angular-2-quickstart-app-to-google-cloud-platform)

Have no idea about it. Seems we need preinstall tsc on GCP app engine?

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, instead, once you have gained enough reputation, you can [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to the original question